# Importar arquivo .csv para o servidor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, upload, csv

Estou realizando uma tarefa para importar dados de um arquivo .csv para o servidor. 
Já consigo importar o arquivo tudo certinho no lado do servidor, porém cada arquivo contém cerca de 25 mil registros e o usuário fica aguardando até completar o upload. Eu coloquei um simples load na página enquanto o usuário aguarda. 
Porém gostaria de saber se tem alguma biblioteca que cria uma barra com o status de upload para que o usuário saiba quanto tempo resta pra finalizar o upload.

Comment: sua aplicação é webforms?

Comment: Olá @MarconcilioSouza é em MVC

Comment: Olá, veja essa pergunta aqui.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545780/bootstrap-progress-bar-for-mvc-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Tem algumas, como o [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). [Aqui tem um artigo que explica como implementar para o ASP.NET MVC](http://hayageek.com/jquery-multiple-file-upload/).

[O dropzone.js é outra solução elegante, com o mesmo princípio](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).

Mais alguns:

- [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php);
- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/);
- [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/);

Mas acredito também que você quer processar o CSV e reportar o usuário do progresso disso. Esta parte é explicada pelo Dino Esposito em duas partes, [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580729.aspx) e [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708746.aspx), respectivamente.